# UserDefaults implementation always has null in extension

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying so save persisting data to my Userdefault storage so I can use it inside my extension.

**Question
How do I implement this so I can update my view(update value of toggle) when another target is run, in my case an extension. I created the same app group. For my userdefaults**

App is structured like this first my UserDefaults implementation

```
extension UserDefaults {


static let group = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.carlpalsson.superapp")

func save<T: Codable>(_ object: T, forKey key: String) {
       let encoder = JSONEncoder()
       if let encodedObject = try? encoder.encode(object) {
           UserDefaults.group?.set(encodedObject, forKey: key)
           UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
       }
   }

   func getObject<T: Codable>(forKey key: String) -> T? {
       if let object = UserDefaults.group?.object(forKey: key) as? Data {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           if let decodedObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: object) {
               return decodedObject
           }
       }
       return nil
   }


}
  class UserSettings : ObservableObject {

let test = FamilyActivitySelection()

@Published var discouragedAppsCategoryTokens : Set<ActivityCategoryToken> {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.group?.save(discouragedAppsCategoryTokens, forKey:"DiscourageAppsCategoryTokens")
    }
}
 init() {
      
        self.discouragedAppsCategoryTokens  = 
(UserDefaults.group?.getObject(forKey: "DiscourageAppsCategoryTokens")) ?? appcategorytokens
       }

static var shared: UserSettings {
    return _userSettings
}
 }
```

In my extension

```
class MyDeviceActivityMonitor: DeviceActivityMonitor {

let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
let userSettings = UserSettings.shared
let korven = UserSettings()

override func intervalDidStart(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {

  do{
  //Im trying to my values here but it´s always null
   var family = userSettings.DiscouragedAppsFamilyActivitySelection
   var familys: FamilyActivitySelection? = UserDefaults.group?.getObject(forKey: "DiscouragedAppsFamilyActivitySelection")
     
   var iii = korven.DiscouragedAppsFamilyActivitySelection
      
   }  
 }
```

Inside my  @main

```
 @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings.shared

    

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
                .environmentObject(store)
                .environmentObject(userSettings)
        }
    }
```

And in my view

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var userSettings : UserSettings
  VStack {
            Button("Select Apps to Discourage") {
                isDiscouragedPresented = true
            }
            .familyActivityPicker(isPresented: $isDiscouragedPresented, selection: $userSettings.DiscouragedAppsFamilyActivitySelection)
  
   .onChange(of: userSettings.DiscouragedAppsFamilyActivitySelection) { newSelection in
            UserSettings.shared.DiscouragedAppsFamilyActivitySelection = newSelection
            
            MyModel.shared.startDiscourageApps()
          // MySchedule.setSchedule()
        }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(MyModel())
        .environmentObject(UserSettings())
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to update your UI in your extension when the user defaults value changes in your app.  This certainly is possible, but requires some more code on your side.

In your UserSettings class you currently read the user defaults in the initializer and then leave it as is. To get your UI to update you also need to update your property in there when the actual user defaults change. To do this you need to *observe* the user defaults. The easy way would be using the Notification Center with the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`. In your case this won’t work as this notification only is sent for changes made in the same process.

Changes from a different process can be observed using Key-Value-Observing (KVO) though. Unfortunately this seems to be impossible using the nice Swift `KeyPath` API. Instead you have to do that using the Objective-C version. To do this you would make your UserSettings class inherit `NSObject` and implement [`observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416553-observevalue). In there you can read the new data from the user defaults. Then you can add your object as an observer on the user defaults using [`addObserver(_:forKeyPath:options:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412787-addobserver). Options can stay empty and context can be `nil`.

Comment: First of all thank your for answering my question. I Ediths my question, my problems is more that the order container my extension always get nil value from my Userdefaults or the empty object i init the class with. How can I get the orgel container to access the same data?